# Proof that every number can be represented as the sum of two squares and a pronic

Tags: number-theory

Does anyone know of a proof that every positive integer can be represented as $a^2+b^2+ c^2 + c$ where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are nonnegative integers?

I believe that Goldbach asserted this, along with other ways of representing any number, but I can't find a proof.

Comment: Every positif number ? Did you mean integer ? Otherwise take 3.1 and ...

Comment: Any reasonable reader would conclude that the OP meant "whole number" in that context.

Comment: I agree with @GregMartin however I feel the answer should indeed include whole number to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N$ be the positive integer that you want to represent as $a^2+b^2+c^2+c$. By the [three-squares theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), $4N+1$ can be written as the sum of three squares, say $4N+1 = x^2+y^2+z^2$. Since all squares are $0$ or $1$ (mod $4$), exactly two of these three squares are even; without loss of generality, suppose $x$ and $y$ are even and $z$ is odd, and write $x=2a$, $y=2b$, and $z=2c+1$. Then $4N+1 = 4a^2 + 4b^2 + 4c^2+4c+1$, which means that $N=a^2+b^2+c^2+c$ as desired.

Of course, the three-squares theorem is not an easy one to prove, but it is standard and classical.

Answer (score 1):

there exist a and b satisfying  $a^2+b^2+c^2+c=k$ if and only if $k-c^2-c$ has all of its factors of the form $4k+3$ an even number of times.

We need to prove for any natural number k there exists a number c such that $k^2-c^2-c$ that has all of its factors of the form $4k+3$ an even number of times.

Comment: I suspect this idea is not going to lead to a proof, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it's unfortunate, since you found one, I was just offering my two cents, nice answer by the way.